# How to I modify one axis of a rotation matrix?

Tags: opengl, matrix, rotation

I'm currently creating a billboard shader for a game engine and I want to reset the rotation of the quad in this shader. I'm programming the shader in GLSL, here is the vertex shader:

```
#version 400 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 in_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 in_texcoords;

out data
{
    vec2 tex_coords;
} vs_out;

uniform mat4 pr_matrix;
uniform mat4 ml_matrix = mat4(1.0);
uniform mat4 vw_matrix = mat4(1.0);

void main()
{
    gl_Position = pr_matrix * vw_matrix * ml_matrix * vec4(in_position, 1.0);
    vs_out.tex_coords = in_texcoords;
}
```

I know that I can reset the rotation of the model matrix by setting the top left to

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

, but now I want the quad to be able to be rotated around the x and z axis, but not around the y axis. Does anybody know how to reset the rotation of a matrix only on one axis?

Answer (score 0):

This could be of help. Solution uses a solved out rotation matrix, except ported to GLSL. There are many versions of a rotation matrix depending on whether you want to recycle the trig functions (cos/sin). Since GFX are better at SIMD, this function is coded in respect to that.

```
mat4 rotationMatrix(vec3 axis, float angle)
{
    axis = normalize(axis);
    float s = sin(angle);
    float c = cos(angle);
    float oc = 1.0 - c;

    return mat4(oc * axis.x * axis.x + c,           oc * axis.x * axis.y - axis.z * s,  oc * axis.z * axis.x + axis.y * s,  0.0,
                oc * axis.x * axis.y + axis.z * s,  oc * axis.y * axis.y + c,           oc * axis.y * axis.z - axis.x * s,  0.0,
                oc * axis.z * axis.x - axis.y * s,  oc * axis.y * axis.z + axis.x * s,  oc * axis.z * axis.z + c,           0.0,
                0.0,                                0.0,                                0.0,                                1.0);
}
```

Source: http://www.neilmendoza.com/glsl-rotation-about-an-arbitrary-axis/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but do you know how to set the euler angle around the y axis to 0? Because thats what I am looking for :/

Comment: @RagingRabbit: Can you multiply by the inverse of the y axis only, to undo that specific rotation?

Comment: No, I've only got the transformation matrix, so the rotation on all axis.